# Why is this ARRAYFORMULA + VLOOKUP() + REGEXEXTRACT() with multiple conditions not working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a sheet, I have public images whose links are like this `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gnl6ODS5sinOPsd0fcvszbA-bduNE2I/view?usp=sharing`
and the result should be: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-gnl6ODS5sinOPsd0fcvszbA-bduNE2I`.

So, I'm working on this formula to have it the expected yield:
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-gnl6ODS5sinOPsd0fcvszbA-bduNE2I`

**The formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,Image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&regexextract(VLOOKUP($J$3:$J&" "&$N1:$N$1,
 QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!A1:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!C1:C"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!F1:F")}, 
 "select Col1,Col3"), 2, 0)),"d/(.+)/view")))
```

This is the [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing), in case you feel like giving it a shot.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,Image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&regexextract(VLOOKUP($J$3:$J&" "&$N1:$N$1,
 QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!A1:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!C1:C"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU","Image Link!F1:F")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2"), 2, 0),"d/(.+)/view"))))
```

**Result:**
[image]